# "If done correctly, ..."

Tags: terminology

Could you please tell me what does "if done correctly" mean in this sentence?

*If done correctly, all existentialism is applied existentialism.*

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please show what your own research yields. What information does a dictionary give you about those words. Please have a look at the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about posting good questions.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what puzzles you about the phrase "if done correctly".

Comment: Does "done" refer to "existentialism"? If so, what does "done" exactly mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Participle form of verbs can be used after the conjunctions *if, when* to shorten the sentence, but they convey exactly the same meaning as time and conditional clauses.

**If done correctly = If it is done correctly.**

Comment: Thank you so much dear Turkan. I know it,but what I don't understand is the meaning of "done" in relation to "existentialism".I would be grateful if you explain it.